# Excel Web Access webpart shows error in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, migration, excel-web-access-webpart

I am migrating SharePoint 2013 web application to SharePoint 2016 using content database backup/restore approach. I am seeing below error message for all "Excel Web Access" webpart instances in SharePoint 2016. As per my analysis, this web part is depricated in SharePoint 2016, I have refered https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346112(v=office.16).aspx article. Please let me know if there are any alternatives to get this web part functionality working in SharePoint 2016.

> **Web Part Error:** A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be
>   displayed or imported. The type
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.ExcelWebRenderer,
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c could not be found or it is not
>   registered as safe. Correlation ID:
>   7199339e-19f1-d0c4-efb6-875b7682c91c.

Comment: In order to display Excel workbooks in the browser, you must deploy Office Online Server. Have you done that?

Comment: No, I did not deploy the Office Online Server yet. Do I need to reconfigure the "Excel Web Access" web parts once I deploy the Office Online Server?

Answer (score 1):

As you know excel service application is now part of OOS, You need to configure it then yes it will fix the error.

> If you currently use Excel Services in SharePoint 2013 and upgrade to
>   SharePoint Server 2016 you must also deploy Office Online Server with
>   Excel Online to ensure Excel Services functionality remains available.
>
> The following Excel Services functionality requires Excel Online in
>   Office Online Server:
>
> 1. Viewing and editing Excel workbooks in a browser (with or without
>      the Data Model)
> 2. **Excel Web Access web part for SharePoint**
> 3. ODC file support (no longer requires Data Connection Libraries)
> 4. Programmability features such as JavaScript OM, User Defined
>      Function Assemblies, SOAP and REST protocol support

[What's deprecated or removed from SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346112%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and look for Excel Services in SharePoint section.